# How to push a UIImagePickerController (or visually alike)

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to push image picker like normal view controller, but after investigating I found that UIImagePickerController is a UINavigationController, I can not push it.

And I try to use imager picker to push other VC, pushing is fine, but the status bar is missing. Code is below

```
[imagePicker pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

So, is there any way to push image picker or use image picker push other view controller ?
(or at least visually alike) (third party open source modules accept if using and looking like image picker)